# RF PCB Layout for 915Mhz + BLE: Which is better?

Tags: pcb, rf, spi, layout

I am designing a small board with a 915Mhz transceiver IC breakout (based on the CC1101 + CC1190 chipsets), controlled by an STM32. I have used the popular nrf24l01 chipset in the past, but was disappointed by the limited range and poor penetration through walls, so I decided to try using an amplified sub 1Ghz option.

The board has an nRF52 co-processor on board, to allow me to do higher bandwidth wireless debugging over BLE to a PC, as well as send over-the air firmware updates.

My first pass had both radios laid out next to each other in parallel, as shown in the image below. After routing, I started thinking that this is a poor choice in layout, since it places the two SMA antenna connectors parallel and in very close proximity to each other, which might cause RF interference (maybe even near field effects? harmonics?) that could significantly reduce the performance of each radio. I also thought  that there might be interference with the SPI bus shared between the nRF52 and STM32 introduced by the parallel placement of the 915Mhz radio.

[image]

I then decided to modify the layout so that the antennae were at 90 degrees from one another, like this. My reasoning is that making the 'direction' of the RF circuits orthogonal to each other will minimize interference (with the added benefit of shorter and more isolated SPI traces). I also have some vague impression that cutting the board up with the radio sections in jutted-out strips like this will help prevent the copper on my board from sinking radiated emissions from the transmitters.  [image]

I'm inexperienced with RF electronics and am unsure whether my logic is sound. Is one of these layouts better than the other? Does it not matter? (because the SMA antennae are hinged and manually adjustable, or because the large difference in operating frequency between the two radios means they're unlikely to interfere?)

Comment: Not an RF comment - but looking at the 1st board, is there even enough clearance between the pair of SMAs to be able to screw an antenna onto each of them without the 1st one interfering with the 2nd?

Comment: @brhans there wasn't! I edited my post with a slightly tweaked layout for the 'parallel' option that gives it enough clearance. Good catch

Comment: Your first layout is not bad, and the second one is not necessarily better.  What steps have you taken to ensure that you have the proper isolation between the two RF channels (radios)?

Comment: Also, note the SMA connectors themselves are not going to be your problem with either layout.

Comment: Four layer board? There’s no rf fencing (row of vias) to stop the rf propogating through the board. Top layer fills need to be tied to the groundplane otherwise they become antennas.

Comment: It's a 4 layer yes. 3.3V and GND for the inner 2 planes, top and bottom ground as well. I do use multiple vias to tie islands on the top and bottom to the inner ground layer, but it can't hurt to do more

Comment: ah, looks like RF fencing means something a little more particular. It also looks like my layer stack order is wrong; gnd plane should be directly under the top layer

Comment: @Ocanath - Do you understand what is meant by RF fencing, or via fencing?

Comment: I believe so. I did not do this in the design I posted. It looks like it entails simply placing a row of vias on both sides of an RF line to connect the surrounding ground plane 'waveguide' to the inner ground plane, which provides better RF isolation

Comment: You got it!  Though to do it right, you have to know how far to place them from the trace so as to maintain the desired impedance (this spacing is not too critical) and the spacing between vias to give you the isolation required.  The higher the frequencies of concern and the higher the desired isolation, the closer the spacing.